# Python: merge duplicates by unique column in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, unique

I've got a problem with my python code. I'm trying to merge rows in my data frame. I've got something like that:

| CODE_ID | SIZE | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ... | 18 | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Big | X | . | . | . | ... | . | abc |
| 12345 | Big | . | X | . | . | ... | . | def |
| 67890 | Medium | . | . | . | X | ... | . | ghi |
| 67890 | Medium | . | . | X | . | ... | . | jkl |
| 13579 | Small | . | . | . | X | ... | . | xyz |

I would like to merge the duplicates by CODE_ID, but strings in CODE column I'd like to join. Just like that:

| CODE_ID | SIZE | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ... | 18 | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Big | X | X | . | . | ... | . | abc; def |
| 67890 | Medium | . | . | X | X | ... | . | ghi; jkl |
| 13579 | Small | . | . | . | X | ... | . | xyz |

I did it with agg, but it's just part of work.

```
g_df = df.groupby("CODE_ID")
group = g_df["CODE"].agg(lambda column: "; ".join(column))
group = group.reset_index(name="CODE")
```

Because the result is like that:

| CODE_ID | CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | abc; def |
| 67890 | ghi; jkl |
| 13579 | xyz |

How can I add the rest of columns? Or maybe it's the wrong way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert `X`s and `.`s to 1/0, then `groupby` and `max`, and map it back to `X`s and `.`s:

```
(df
     .set_index(['CODE_ID', 'SIZE'])
     .filter(regex='\d+')              # numeric column names
     .replace({'X': 1, '.': 0})        # map to 1/0s
     .groupby(level=[0, 1])            # groupby code and size
     .max()                            # max
     .replace({1: 'X', 0: '.'})        # map back to X/.
).merge(                               # add ;-separated codes
    df.groupby(['CODE_ID', 'SIZE'])["CODE"].apply('; '.join),
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
)
```

Output:

```
   CODE_ID    SIZE  1  2  3  4 18      CODE
0    12345     Big  X  X  .  .  .  abc; def
1    13579   Small  .  .  .  X  .       xyz
2    67890  Medium  .  .  X  X  .  ghi; jkl
```